# cannot connect to server via wss

Tags: security, ssl, nginx, websocket

I have the below `nginx.conf` file set to handle http and https. I'm currently using a self-signed certificate to test over ssl.

```
  server {
        listen       80;

    listen      443 ssl;

    server_name  localhost;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://node:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location /socketcluster/ {
        proxy_pass http://node:8000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
```

When i try to connect via `localhost` . `http`,`https` & `ws://` seem to work fine. However when the client tries to connect via `wss://` . i get the below error

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://localhost:80/socketcluster/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

my nginx log shows this -

```
nginx       | 172.18.0.1 - - [25/Aug/2016:20:34:51 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x00\x7F\x01\x00\x00{\x03\x02\xB0\x80r\xEEH\x8C\x03\xAFFw\x9A4\xC2\x84\xB6\xD9\x9E;|\xDFbD\x1D\xF6)Ai\xB3<C\x13O\x00\x00\x10\xC0" 400 173 "-" "-"
```

Is there something additional i have to be adding to the nginx conf file to get `wss://` to work?